# Java VisualVM MBeans plugin

Tags: visualvm

I am running JDK 1.8.0_66 JVisualVM utility and want to use MBeans browser to Monitor my Coherence applications.

According to the Oracle tutorial I have to install the MBeans plugin first. So I went to **Tools-Plugins-Available Plugins** and there were no any available plugins. I checked my JDK installation for `*.nbm` files and found nothing.

What do I need to do to install MBeans plugin for JVisualVM? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that once you do have the plugins list, the MBeans plugin may show up as "VisualVM-MBeans".

Answer (score 13):

When accessing https://visualvm.java.net I get redirected to http://www.oracle.com/splash/java.net/maintenance/index.html which states that the page has been closed.

Thus I think you have to download and install the plugins manually.

1. Go to https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html
2. Choose the link to "Java VisualVM" according to your JDK version
3. Download the tool manually
4. Select "Tools" -> "Plugins" -> "Downloaded" tab to install the downloaded file

Worked for me.

Comment: I found the solution of my problem here. It works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It appears the visualvm site has moved to github.io, so the links are broken. I just updated mine to the correct one on found on
https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html

In VisualVM go to Tools -> Plugins -> Settings, Edit Java VisualVM Plugins Center, and change the URL to the correct URL for your VisualVM, ex: 
https://visualvm.github.io/archive/uc/8u40/updates.xml.gz

After this I was able to update & install plugins using the UI again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be connected to internet and you should have access to https://visualvm.java.net

Comment: I am connected, but I am behind a firewall,

Comment: In that case you need specify your proxy settings in Tools->Options->Network